# Reading Excel ROW using OleDb data retrieval

Tags: c#, excel

Any help what I am doing wrong here? if I am trying to read the only row for an example TestCaseName to `case_1` then i'm getting the data of different row.

How can I make sure its only read what is being requested to read? and I am using the where clause but seems like does not filter it.

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", EXCELFILENAME);

string testCaseName = "case_1
string query = String.Format("SELECT * from [{0}$] WHERE TestCaseName=\"{1}\"", workbookName, testCaseName);

OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);  
DataTable myTable = dataSet.Tables[0]; 

TestCaseName       Name    Active   Status  etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------
case_1             Tom     yes      Completed   etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------
case_2             John    yes                  etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------
case_3             Jim     yes                  etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------
case_4             Don     yes                  etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------
case_5             Sam     yes      Visitor     etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is "columns" representing in your SQL ?

Comment: it was a typo it should be `TestCaseName` instead of `columns`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error using pretty much the same code. The only difference between yours and mine is that I created an OleDbConnection object and used that in the constructor of the OleDbDataAdapter. But I wouldn't have though it would make the difference you've indicated. Have you checked that your Excel sheet does not contain any blank rows above the headers?

Comment: I am not getting error but its mixing up the data for an ex if I want to retrieve the data for case2 then I was getting the case1 data. Can u post ur code? How you have tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I tested with. It appears to work perfectly. If your doesn't then I can only assume that your spreadsheet is not structured quite the same as mine.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
string testCaseName = "case_1";
string query = "SELECT * from [Sheet1$] WHERE TestCaseName=\"" + testCaseName + "\"";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```